# Export to excel multiple sheets/tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently using the following code to export to excel and it works perfectly:

```
Response.ClearContent()
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Responses.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

GridView1.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
Response.End();
```

However, I want to be able to add new tab/sheet into the same excel file. How to do this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. But you'll have to do a little reverse engineering. First, let's create a demo document. Open Excel, and give yourself a few sheets. Add some text on each sheet. Then do a Save As and save it as a Single File Web Page (.mhtml) file. Then close Excel, rename the extension from .MHTML to .XLS. Then open the file. You'll get a warning message. Tell it yes it's okay to open. Then you'll see both sheets. From this point, inspect the contents of the .XLS file with a text editor such as Notepad or Notepad++. You can see how they embed the data for each sheet within the file. When you generate the HTML on the server, use the same format as what you learned from inspecting the HTML file. The contents of mine are below as an example.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Document-Type: Workbook
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_01CFFA76.49BAAF50"

This document is a Single File Web Page, also known as a Web Archive file.  If you are seeing this message, your browser or editor doesn't support Web Archive files.  Please download a browser that supports Web Archive, such as Windows® Internet Explorer®.

------=_NextPart_01CFFA76.49BAAF50
Content-Location: file:///C:/D1745AB1/test1.htm
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

<html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta name=3D"Excel Workbook Frameset">
<meta http-equiv=3DContent-Type content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii">
<meta name=3DProgId content=3DExcel.Sheet>
<meta name=3DGenerator content=3D"Microsoft Excel 14">
<link rel=3DFile-List href=3D"test1_files/filelist.xml">
<![if !supportTabStrip]>
<link id=3D"shLink" href=3D"test1_files/sheet001.htm">
<link id=3D"shLink" href=3D"test1_files/sheet002.htm">

<link id=3D"shLink">

<script language=3D"JavaScript">
<!--
 var c_lTabs=3D2;

 var c_rgszSh=3Dnew Array(c_lTabs);
 c_rgszSh[0] =3D "Book1";
 c_rgszSh[1] =3D "Sheet1";



 var c_rgszClr=3Dnew Array(8);
 c_rgszClr[0]=3D"window";
 c_rgszClr[1]=3D"buttonface";
 c_rgszClr[2]=3D"windowframe";
 c_rgszClr[3]=3D"windowtext";
 c_rgszClr[4]=3D"threedlightshadow";
 c_rgszClr[5]=3D"threedhighlight";
 c_rgszClr[6]=3D"threeddarkshadow";
 c_rgszClr[7]=3D"threedshadow";

 var g_iShCur;
 var g_rglTabX=3Dnew Array(c_lTabs);

function fnGetIEVer()
{
 var ua=3Dwindow.navigator.userAgent
 var msie=3Dua.indexOf("MSIE")
 if (msie>0 && window.navigator.platform=3D=3D"Win32")
  return parseInt(ua.substring(msie+5,ua.indexOf(".", msie)));
 else
  return 0;
}

function fnBuildFrameset()
{
 var szHTML=3D"<frameset rows=3D\"*,18\" border=3D0 width=3D0 frameborder=
=3Dno framespacing=3D0>"+
  "<frame src=3D\""+document.all.item("shLink")[1].href+"\" name=3D\"frShee=
t\" noresize>"+
  "<frameset cols=3D\"54,*\" border=3D0 width=3D0 frameborder=3Dno framespa=
cing=3D0>"+
  "<frame src=3D\"\" name=3D\"frScroll\" marginwidth=3D0 marginheight=3D0 s=
crolling=3Dno>"+
  "<frame src=3D\"\" name=3D\"frTabs\" marginwidth=3D0 marginheight=3D0 scr=
olling=3Dno>"+
  "</frameset></frameset><plaintext>";

 with (document) {
  open("text/html","replace");
  write(szHTML);
  close();
 }

 fnBuildTabStrip();
}

function fnBuildTabStrip()
{
 var szHTML=3D
  "<html><head><style>.clScroll {font:8pt Courier New;color:"+c_rgszClr[6]+=
";cursor:default;line-height:10pt;}"+
  ".clScroll2 {font:10pt Arial;color:"+c_rgszClr[6]+";cursor:default;line-h=
eight:11pt;}</style></head>"+
  "<body onclick=3D\"event.returnValue=3Dfalse;\" ondragstart=3D\"event.ret=
urnValue=3Dfalse;\" onselectstart=3D\"event.returnValue=3Dfalse;\" bgcolor=
=3D"+c_rgszClr[4]+" topmargin=3D0 leftmargin=3D0><table cellpadding=3D0 cel=
lspacing=3D0 width=3D100%>"+
  "<tr><td colspan=3D6 height=3D1 bgcolor=3D"+c_rgszClr[2]+"></td></tr>"+
  "<tr><td style=3D\"font:1pt\">&nbsp;<td>"+
  "<td valign=3Dtop id=3DtdScroll class=3D\"clScroll\" onclick=3D\"parent.f=
nFastScrollTabs(0);\" onmouseover=3D\"parent.fnMouseOverScroll(0);\" onmous=
eout=3D\"parent.fnMouseOutScroll(0);\"><a>&#171;</a></td>"+
  "<td valign=3Dtop id=3DtdScroll class=3D\"clScroll2\" onclick=3D\"parent.=
fnScrollTabs(0);\" ondblclick=3D\"parent.fnScrollTabs(0);\" onmouseover=3D\=
"parent.fnMouseOverScroll(1);\" onmouseout=3D\"parent.fnMouseOutScroll(1);\=
"><a>&lt</a></td>"+
  "<td valign=3Dtop id=3DtdScroll class=3D\"clScroll2\" onclick=3D\"parent.=
fnScrollTabs(1);\" ondblclick=3D\"parent.fnScrollTabs(1);\" onmouseover=3D\=
"parent.fnMouseOverScroll(2);\" onmouseout=3D\"parent.fnMouseOutScroll(2);\=
"><a>&gt</a></td>"+
  "<td valign=3Dtop id=3DtdScroll class=3D\"clScroll\" onclick=3D\"parent.f=
nFastScrollTabs(1);\" onmouseover=3D\"parent.fnMouseOverScroll(3);\" onmous=
eout=3D\"parent.fnMouseOutScroll(3);\"><a>&#187;</a></td>"+
  "<td style=3D\"font:1pt\">&nbsp;<td></tr></table></body></html>";

 with (frames['frScroll'].document) {
  open("text/html","replace");
  write(szHTML);
  close();
 }

 szHTML =3D
  "<html><head>"+
  "<style>A:link,A:visited,A:active {text-decoration:none;"+"color:"+c_rgsz=
Clr[3]+";}"+
  ".clTab {cursor:hand;background:"+c_rgszClr[1]+";font:9pt Arial;padding-l=
eft:3px;padding-right:3px;text-align:center;}"+
  ".clBorder {background:"+c_rgszClr[2]+";font:1pt;}"+
  "</style></head><body onload=3D\"parent.fnInit();\" onselectstart=3D\"eve=
nt.returnValue=3Dfalse;\" ondragstart=3D\"event.returnValue=3Dfalse;\" bgco=
lor=3D"+c_rgszClr[4]+
  " topmargin=3D0 leftmargin=3D0><table id=3DtbTabs cellpadding=3D0 cellspa=
cing=3D0>";

 var iCellCount=3D(c_lTabs+1)*2;

 var i;
 for (i=3D0;i<iCellCount;i+=3D2)
  szHTML+=3D"<col width=3D1><col>";

 var iRow;
 for (iRow=3D0;iRow<6;iRow++) {

  szHTML+=3D"<tr>";

  if (iRow=3D=3D5)
   szHTML+=3D"<td colspan=3D"+iCellCount+"></td>";
  else {
   if (iRow=3D=3D0) {
    for(i=3D0;i<iCellCount;i++)
     szHTML+=3D"<td height=3D1 class=3D\"clBorder\"></td>";
   } else if (iRow=3D=3D1) {
    for(i=3D0;i<c_lTabs;i++) {
     szHTML+=3D"<td height=3D1 nowrap class=3D\"clBorder\">&nbsp;</td>";
     szHTML+=3D
      "<td id=3DtdTab height=3D1 nowrap class=3D\"clTab\" onmouseover=3D\"p=
arent.fnMouseOverTab("+i+");\" onmouseout=3D\"parent.fnMouseOutTab("+i+");\=
">"+
      "<a href=3D\""+document.all.item("shLink")[i].href+"\" target=3D\"frS=
heet\" id=3DaTab>&nbsp;"+c_rgszSh[i]+"&nbsp;</a></td>";
    }
    szHTML+=3D"<td id=3DtdTab height=3D1 nowrap class=3D\"clBorder\"><a id=
=3DaTab>&nbsp;</a></td><td width=3D100%></td>";
   } else if (iRow=3D=3D2) {
    for (i=3D0;i<c_lTabs;i++)
     szHTML+=3D"<td height=3D1></td><td height=3D1 class=3D\"clBorder\"></t=
d>";
    szHTML+=3D"<td height=3D1></td><td height=3D1></td>";
   } else if (iRow=3D=3D3) {
    for (i=3D0;i<iCellCount;i++)
     szHTML+=3D"<td height=3D1></td>";
   } else if (iRow=3D=3D4) {
    for (i=3D0;i<c_lTabs;i++)
     szHTML+=3D"<td height=3D1 width=3D1></td><td height=3D1></td>";
    szHTML+=3D"<td height=3D1 width=3D1></td><td></td>";
   }
  }
  szHTML+=3D"</tr>";
 }

 szHTML+=3D"</table></body></html>";
 with (frames['frTabs'].document) {
  open("text/html","replace");
  charset=3Ddocument.charset;
  write(szHTML);
  close();
 }
}

function fnInit()
{
 g_rglTabX[0]=3D0;
 var i;
 for (i=3D1;i<=3Dc_lTabs;i++)
  with (frames['frTabs'].document.all.tbTabs.rows[1].cells[fnTabToCol(i-1)])
   g_rglTabX[i]=3DoffsetLeft+offsetWidth-6;
}

function fnTabToCol(iTab)
{
 return 2*iTab+1;
}

function fnNextTab(fDir)
{
 var iNextTab=3D-1;
 var i;

 with (frames['frTabs'].document.body) {
  if (fDir=3D=3D0) {
   if (scrollLeft>0) {
    for (i=3D0;i<c_lTabs&&g_rglTabX[i]<scrollLeft;i++);
    if (i<c_lTabs)
     iNextTab=3Di-1;
   }
  } else {
   if (g_rglTabX[c_lTabs]+6>offsetWidth+scrollLeft) {
    for (i=3D0;i<c_lTabs&&g_rglTabX[i]<=3DscrollLeft;i++);
    if (i<c_lTabs)
     iNextTab=3Di;
   }
  }
 }
 return iNextTab;
}

function fnScrollTabs(fDir)
{
 var iNextTab=3DfnNextTab(fDir);

 if (iNextTab>=3D0) {
  frames['frTabs'].scroll(g_rglTabX[iNextTab],0);
  return true;
 } else
  return false;
}

function fnFastScrollTabs(fDir)
{
 if (c_lTabs>16)
  frames['frTabs'].scroll(g_rglTabX[fDir?c_lTabs-1:0],0);
 else
  if (fnScrollTabs(fDir)>0) window.setTimeout("fnFastScrollTabs("+fDir+");"=
,5);
}

function fnSetTabProps(iTab,fActive)
{
 var iCol=3DfnTabToCol(iTab);
 var i;

 if (iTab>=3D0) {
  with (frames['frTabs'].document.all) {
   with (tbTabs) {
    for (i=3D0;i<=3D4;i++) {
     with (rows[i]) {
      if (i=3D=3D0)
       cells[iCol].style.background=3Dc_rgszClr[fActive?0:2];
      else if (i>0 && i<4) {
       if (fActive) {
        cells[iCol-1].style.background=3Dc_rgszClr[2];
        cells[iCol].style.background=3Dc_rgszClr[0];
        cells[iCol+1].style.background=3Dc_rgszClr[2];
       } else {
        if (i=3D=3D1) {
         cells[iCol-1].style.background=3Dc_rgszClr[2];
         cells[iCol].style.background=3Dc_rgszClr[1];
         cells[iCol+1].style.background=3Dc_rgszClr[2];
        } else {
         cells[iCol-1].style.background=3Dc_rgszClr[4];
         cells[iCol].style.background=3Dc_rgszClr[(i=3D=3D2)?2:4];
         cells[iCol+1].style.background=3Dc_rgszClr[4];
        }
       }
      } else
       cells[iCol].style.background=3Dc_rgszClr[fActive?2:4];
     }
    }
   }
   with (aTab[iTab].style) {
    cursor=3D(fActive?"default":"hand");
    color=3Dc_rgszClr[3];
   }
  }
 }
}

function fnMouseOverScroll(iCtl)
{
 frames['frScroll'].document.all.tdScroll[iCtl].style.color=3Dc_rgszClr[7];
}

function fnMouseOutScroll(iCtl)
{
 frames['frScroll'].document.all.tdScroll[iCtl].style.color=3Dc_rgszClr[6];
}

function fnMouseOverTab(iTab)
{
 if (iTab!=3Dg_iShCur) {
  var iCol=3DfnTabToCol(iTab);
  with (frames['frTabs'].document.all) {
   tdTab[iTab].style.background=3Dc_rgszClr[5];
  }
 }
}

function fnMouseOutTab(iTab)
{
 if (iTab>=3D0) {
  var elFrom=3Dframes['frTabs'].event.srcElement;
  var elTo=3Dframes['frTabs'].event.toElement;

  if ((!elTo) ||
   (elFrom.tagName=3D=3DelTo.tagName) ||
   (elTo.tagName=3D=3D"A" && elTo.parentElement!=3DelFrom) ||
   (elFrom.tagName=3D=3D"A" && elFrom.parentElement!=3DelTo)) {

   if (iTab!=3Dg_iShCur) {
    with (frames['frTabs'].document.all) {
     tdTab[iTab].style.background=3Dc_rgszClr[1];
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

function fnSetActiveSheet(iSh)
{
 if (iSh!=3Dg_iShCur) {
  fnSetTabProps(g_iShCur,false);
  fnSetTabProps(iSh,true);
  g_iShCur=3DiSh;
 }
}

 window.g_iIEVer=3DfnGetIEVer();
 if (window.g_iIEVer>=3D4)
  fnBuildFrameset();
//-->
</script>
<![endif]><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <x:ExcelWorkbook>
  <x:ExcelWorksheets>
   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
    <x:Name>Book1</x:Name>
    <x:WorksheetSource HRef=3D"test1_files/sheet001.htm"/>
   </x:ExcelWorksheet>
   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
    <x:Name>Sheet1</x:Name>
    <x:WorksheetSource HRef=3D"test1_files/sheet002.htm"/>
   </x:ExcelWorksheet>
  </x:ExcelWorksheets>
  <x:Stylesheet HRef=3D"test1_files/stylesheet.css"/>
  <x:WindowHeight>12585</x:WindowHeight>
  <x:WindowWidth>27795</x:WindowWidth>
  <x:WindowTopX>480</x:WindowTopX>
  <x:WindowTopY>120</x:WindowTopY>
  <x:ActiveSheet>1</x:ActiveSheet>
  <x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure>
  <x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows>
 </x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>

<frameset rows=3D"*,39" border=3D0 width=3D0 frameborder=3Dno framespacing=
=3D0>
 <frame src=3D"test1_files/sheet002.htm" name=3D"frSheet">
 <frame src=3D"test1_files/tabstrip.htm" name=3D"frTabs" marginwidth=3D0 ma=
rginheight=3D0>
 <noframes>
  <body>
   <p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>
  </body>
 </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>

------=_NextPart_01CFFA76.49BAAF50
Content-Location: file:///C:/D1745AB1/test1_files/stylesheet.css
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/css; charset="us-ascii"

tr
    {mso-height-source:auto;}
col
    {mso-width-source:auto;}
br
    {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
.style0
    {mso-number-format:General;
    text-align:general;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    white-space:nowrap;
    mso-rotate:0;
    mso-background-source:auto;
    mso-pattern:auto;
    color:black;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    border:none;
    mso-protection:locked visible;
    mso-style-name:Normal;
    mso-style-id:0;}
td
    {mso-style-parent:style0;
    padding-top:1px;
    padding-right:1px;
    padding-left:1px;
    mso-ignore:padding;
    color:black;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-number-format:General;
    text-align:general;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    border:none;
    mso-background-source:auto;
    mso-pattern:auto;
    mso-protection:locked visible;
    white-space:nowrap;
    mso-rotate:0;}
.xl65
    {mso-style-parent:style0;
    color:black;}

------=_NextPart_01CFFA76.49BAAF50
Content-Location: file:///C:/D1745AB1/test1_files/tabstrip.htm
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3DContent-Type content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii">
<meta name=3DProgId content=3DExcel.Sheet>
<meta name=3DGenerator content=3D"Microsoft Excel 14">
<link id=3DMain-File rel=3DMain-File href=3D"../test1.htm">
<![if IE]>
<base href=3D"file:///C:\D1745AB1\test1_files\tabstrip.htm"
id=3D"webarch_temp_base_tag">
<![endif]>
<script language=3D"JavaScript">
<!--
if (window.name!=3D"frTabs")
 window.location.replace(document.all.item("Main-File").href);
//-->
</script>
<style>
<!--
A {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:9pt;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body topmargin=3D0 leftmargin=3D0 bgcolor=3D"#808080">
<table border=3D0 cellspacing=3D1>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor=3D"#FFFFFF" nowrap><b><small><small>&nbsp;<a href=3D"sheet001.=
htm" target=3D"frSheet"><font face=3D"Arial" color=3D"#000000">Book1</font>=
</a>&nbsp;</small></small></b></td>
 <td bgcolor=3D"#FFFFFF" nowrap><b><small><small>&nbsp;<a href=3D"sheet002.=
htm" target=3D"frSheet"><font face=3D"Arial" color=3D"#000000">Sheet1</font=
></a>&nbsp;</small></small></b></td>

 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

------=_NextPart_01CFFA76.49BAAF50
Content-Location: file:///C:/D1745AB1/test1_files/sheet001.htm
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

<html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=3DContent-Type content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii">
<meta name=3DProgId content=3DExcel.Sheet>
<meta name=3DGenerator content=3D"Microsoft Excel 14">
<link id=3DMain-File rel=3DMain-File href=3D"../test1.htm">
<link rel=3DFile-List href=3Dfilelist.xml>
<![if IE]>
<base href=3D"file:///C:\D1745AB1\test1_files\sheet001.htm"
id=3D"webarch_temp_base_tag">
<![endif]>
<link rel=3DStylesheet href=3Dstylesheet.css>
<style>
<!--table
    {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
    mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
@page
    {margin:1.0in .75in 1.0in .75in;
    mso-header-margin:.5in;
    mso-footer-margin:.5in;}
-->
</style>
<![if !supportTabStrip]><script language=3D"JavaScript">
<!--
function fnUpdateTabs()
 {
  if (parent.window.g_iIEVer>=3D4) {
   if (parent.document.readyState=3D=3D"complete"
    && parent.frames['frTabs'].document.readyState=3D=3D"complete")
   parent.fnSetActiveSheet(0);
  else
   window.setTimeout("fnUpdateTabs();",150);
 }
}

if (window.name!=3D"frSheet")
 window.location.replace("../test1.htm");
else
 fnUpdateTabs();
//-->
</script>
<![endif]>
</head>

<body link=3Dblue vlink=3Dpurple>
<!--The following information was generated by Microsoft Excel's Publish as=
 Web
Page wizard.--><!--If the same item is republished from Excel, all informat=
ion between the DIV
tags will be replaced.--><!-----------------------------><!--START OF OUTPU=
T FROM EXCEL PUBLISH AS WEB PAGE WIZARD --><!----------------------------->

<table border=3D0 cellpadding=3D0 cellspacing=3D0 width=3D31 style=3D'borde=
r-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:23pt'>
 <col width=3D31 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:1133;width=
:23pt'>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'mso-height-source:userset;height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl65 width=3D31 style=3D'height:15.0pt;width:23pt=
'>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'mso-height-source:userset;height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl65 style=3D'height:15.0pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![if supportMisalignedColumns]>
 <tr height=3D0 style=3D'display:none'>
  <td width=3D31 style=3D'width:23pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![endif]>
</table>

</body>

</html>

------=_NextPart_01CFFA76.49BAAF50
Content-Location: file:///C:/D1745AB1/test1_files/sheet002.htm
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

<html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=3DContent-Type content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii">
<meta name=3DProgId content=3DExcel.Sheet>
<meta name=3DGenerator content=3D"Microsoft Excel 14">
<link id=3DMain-File rel=3DMain-File href=3D"../test1.htm">
<link rel=3DFile-List href=3Dfilelist.xml>
<![if IE]>
<base href=3D"file:///C:\D1745AB1\test1_files\sheet002.htm"
id=3D"webarch_temp_base_tag">
<![endif]>
<link rel=3DStylesheet href=3Dstylesheet.css>
<style>
<!--table
    {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
    mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
@page
    {margin:.75in .7in .75in .7in;
    mso-header-margin:.3in;
    mso-footer-margin:.3in;}
-->
</style>
<![if !supportTabStrip]><script language=3D"JavaScript">
<!--
function fnUpdateTabs()
 {
  if (parent.window.g_iIEVer>=3D4) {
   if (parent.document.readyState=3D=3D"complete"
    && parent.frames['frTabs'].document.readyState=3D=3D"complete")
   parent.fnSetActiveSheet(1);
  else
   window.setTimeout("fnUpdateTabs();",150);
 }
}

if (window.name!=3D"frSheet")
 window.location.replace("../test1.htm");
else
 fnUpdateTabs();
//-->
</script>
<![endif]>
</head>

<body link=3Dblue vlink=3Dpurple>

<table border=3D0 cellpadding=3D0 cellspacing=3D0 width=3D64 style=3D'borde=
r-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:48pt'>
 <col width=3D64 style=3D'width:48pt'>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 width=3D64 style=3D'height:15.0pt;width:48pt'>test2</td>
 </tr>
 <![if supportMisalignedColumns]>
 <tr height=3D0 style=3D'display:none'>
  <td width=3D64 style=3D'width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![endif]>
</table>

</body>

</html>

------=_NextPart_01CFFA76.49BAAF50
Content-Location: file:///C:/D1745AB1/test1_files/filelist.xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"

<xml xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
 <o:MainFile HRef=3D"../test1.htm"/>
 <o:File HRef=3D"stylesheet.css"/>
 <o:File HRef=3D"tabstrip.htm"/>
 <o:File HRef=3D"sheet001.htm"/>
 <o:File HRef=3D"sheet002.htm"/>
 <o:File HRef=3D"filelist.xml"/>
</xml>
------=_NextPart_01CFFA76.49BAAF50--
```

This approach is a bad one though. Sorry for the bluntness. This approach is generating HTML, but forcing Excel to open it. That's a bad idea for these reasons:

- You want the user to open the file with Excel, so you create it with the .XLS extension. Excel will complain that it's not a proper Excel format, and ask if you really want to open it. It confuses users.
- If you were to save it with the .HTML extension, Excel won't complain, but it's also not likely to be the default program for opening HTML files (their browser is).
- It's hard to control the generated HTML. GridViews have markup that isn't as clean as you would want them. Using the HTML from that directly in Excel is bound to turn out bad.
- Even if you used a decent library for generating the HTML, it's kind of a black magic to get it properly formatted so that it will look how you want it in Excel.

You need to use a library actually capable of generating proper Excel compatible files. Since you're in an ASP.NET environment, that rules out the Office Interop libraries. But you can use the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) libraries or [Open Office XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx). These are capable of actually generating real .XLSX (Open Office XML Spreadsheet) files which are directly compatible with Excel and Open Office/Libre Office etc. Apple's Spreadsheets should be able to open them also.

Comment: What you've done is interesting. It made me think if I could use an existing excel document and add data to it. Is it possible? For my project, I'm asked to automate the generation of a specific excel document that contains multiple sheets, uses functions(e.g. sum, average, countif.. etc) and generates graph based on the data/calcluations. It'd make things much easier for me as all I have to do is enter data in the first sheet only and then excel will do the rest of the calculations and generate the graph.

Comment: Yes. Generate your Excel file, save it as a Single Page Web File, then copy the contents of that file into your program and manipulate it to embed your data. Please note I'm specifically **not** advocating for that approach. I highly feel that you should be going with an EPPlus or Open Office XML SDK based solution as I described in my answer. Those will be far more reliable and maintainable and easier to do. I'm personally a big fan of EPPlus.

Comment: You'e absolutely right! I shall go for EPPlus. Thanks so much :)